# Django Class Based View, set request.session to some value as soon as user lands on a page

Tags: django, session, django-class-based-views

I have the following need:

I have some sports-betting data on my website and I need to display it in different formats according to user's location.
I am talking about odds format, something like this (it's the same value):
decimal: 2.00 (for Europeans)
american: +100 (for Americans)

I have implemented a function that is something like this and works well:

```py
def check_ip_and_set_initial_odds_format(request):
    country = get_country(get_client_ip2(request))['country_name']
    if country == 'United States' and 'odds_format' not in request.session:
        request.session['odds_format'] = 'American'
    return request.session
```

So basically, the idea is that if a user visits my website for the first time, the odds_format gets set automatically and the website already provides the right odds format.

My question is: Can I implement this so that no matter which page the user interacts with for the first time, the odds_format gets set to the right value? For now I have implemented it on the home page, but if someone ends up on my website on a different page, odds would not display correctly.

I know I could just call the function in all my views, but I was thinking of something more clever, like editing the View base class maybe?
If this is the right approach, how would I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Normally you would use a middleware for this.

Comment: You can setup your own context processors. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Comment: @thebjorn Thanks! Works perfectly and easy to implement.